# Celery: Do duplicate tasks get automatically executed?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am running (Django) Celery for scheduling tasks to remote workers w1, w2, w3. Each of these workers has their own queue from which they are consuming tasks placed by a "scheduler", which is another celery task on beat on the master server:

```
w1: q1
w2: q2
w3: q3
```

The scheduler schedules tasks based on a db check, i.e. it will reschedule a task with the same parameters if the db doesn't get updated as per the task's running. So if one or more of the queues are piling up, multiple tasks with the same parameters ("duplicates" from my app's perspective) may be in multiple queues at the same time.

I'm seeing some strange behavior with this: when there are duplicate tasks in multiple queues, if one of the queues runs its instance of the task, just a few milliseconds before, the other queued up "duplicate" tasks get executed. So all of a sudden all the tasks execute at the same time, even if they were enqueued minutes apart from each other.

Is there any documentation or other reference that explains this behavior? Is it known behavior, if so how do I turn it off? I only want one instance of this task to run.